# Multi validation not working in Laravel 5.2

Tags: laravel-5

I want to multi validation. I have two table **classrooms** and **join_class**. **classrooms** table has `class_code` field.
Here is my code:

```
public function postJoinclass(Request $request)
   {
       $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
        'class_code' => 'required',
       ]);
        if ($validator->fails()) {
        return Redirect::back()
            ->withErrors($validator);
        }
        else{
               $class_code = $request->get('class_code');
               if($classroom = joinclass::where('class_code',$class_code)->first())
               {
                   Flash::message('You are already in this classroom');
                   return Redirect::route('joinclass');
                }else{
                       if($classroom = classroomModel::where('class_code','!',$class_code)->first())
                       {
                           Flash::message('Your class code is wrong!');
                           return Redirect::route('joinclass');
                       }else{
                         $class = new joinclass();
                         $class -> user_id = Auth::user()->id;
                         $class -> class_code = $request['class_code'];
                         $class -> save();
                         $class_code = $request->get('class_code');
                         $classroom = classroomModel::where('class_code',$class_code)->first();
                         var_dump($classroom->toArray());
                         return Redirect::route('class',['class_id'=>$classroom->id]);
                         die(var_dump($classroom));
               }
           }
            }

                    return view('class',[

                ])->with('class_id',$request->get('class_id'));
                //->with('classroom',$classroom);
    }
```

Now I want to validate this types:
1) When user put class_code in join class form if in joinclass table has already class_code then print "You are already in this classroom"  
2) If user put wrong code then print "Your code is wrong".
3) If class_code match classrooms table then insert class_code in join table and enter the classroom page.

Now I can't do (2) condition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `exists` validation to do this. [Laravel Validation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/validation#rule-exists)

```
   $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
    'class_code' => 'required|exists:classrooms,class_code',
   ]);
```

### Update:

To specify custom message, you can pass an array of `rule=>message` pair to show custom message. In your case it will be as follows:

```
   $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
    'class_code' => 'required|exists:classrooms,class_code',
   ],[
    'class_code.required' => 'Please specify the Class Code', // change this to your required message
    'class_code.exists' => 'Your code is wrong'
   ]);
```

Comment: I updated the answer to include custom messages.. check it and let me know if it works

Comment: Bro this validation create a problem. that is if new user join a classroom then if join class has already that class_code. than its show you are already in class. I wnat to validation it like one user can not inter 2 time same class. but in one classroom intere many user..

Comment: @Shuvo it can'r be the problem with validator since we did not use any validation on joinclass table